Why do my Christmas lights trip a GFCI only when plugged into a timer switch?
I got tired of plugging and unplugging my outdoor Christmas lights and got an outdoor timer. It’s plugged into an outlet on the same circuit as a GFCI switch. Thats the only change I’ve made to the configuration. The outlet is under a patio cover.
After a week of no issues, I found my GFCI is tripping. It’s happening sometime hours after it turns on. The way I noticed is they weren’t turning on the next day.
Any idea why this is happening? And why didn’t it start happening right away?
I go reset the GFCI and they come on and later turn off at the correct time. Then the next day they don’t turn on again. What is happening?



My hunch is that moisture is getting into the timer. It doesn't take much to cause a ground fault and by its nature a timer is much more complex than just a simple plug. Model # of timer? Picture of timer plugged in with lights plugged into it?

does the GFCI tigers without lights plugged in

pictures would help us help you.  outlet with timer plugged in, outlet without the timer but with the cord.  Also try it again without the timer for a few days and see if that makes a difference.  Weather changed, like dry before timer change and wet after?  GFCI's can be sensitive to subtle changes in moisture, making them trip sometimes and other times not.

The GFCI does not trigger unless the the lights are plugged into the timer. The lights had been fine for weeks until I added the timer. After adding the timer, they were fine for about a week until they started tripping.

The pictures you posted would not show. Looks like you deleted some of the markup needed to make the pictures show.

Wow. That actually looks (for a change) like the right type of timer - actually designed for outdoor use.

Is it/Has it been wet or rainy/snowy lately? Could be the light string is getting wet and causing the GFCI to trip and has nothing to do with the timer.

"Outdoor Extreme Weather Timer" heat/cold tolerant but not actually waterproof, .  "Suitable for damp locations"  but not wet locations.

What happens if you plug something else—not the lights—into the timer?

The receptacle covered with the two flip doors may have been legal when it was constructed, but it is now damaged and sub standard by today's electrical code.
There is obvious water damage and corrosion in the photo.
Code now requires an "in-use box", a WR rated receptacle, and for brick install the manufacturer will require caulking the perimeter of the cover.
Considering the poor condition of the receptacle and unknown lighting connected to it, the timer is unlikely to be the main problem.
If you are really just concerned about the new timer, try it on a different GFCI indoors and connect a lamp to see what happens on a separate and dry circuit.

If (as stated in the question) the problem only occurs with the timer switch in play, there's a ground fault in the timer. As it took a week to manifest, likely due to water having migrated into it over time and not being well-designed for being "weatherproof."
While it is true that the rest of the installation is not up to present code, if the GFCI does not trip without the timer in the line, the problem is in the timer. Of course, if you remove the timer and the problem persists, then the problem happened to manifest coincidentally after you inserted the timer. But if the problem goes away when you remove the timer, that's where the ground fault is.
As a general rule both GFCIs and timers are better located inside, connected to an outlet outside, for trouble-free operation over a long time.

I think equally likely the Christmas lights got wet after a week.  No way to guess from the limited info.

Comment on question states they ran for weeks without the timer, and in most locations that would mean they were exposed to water. However, that case is exactly what 2/3rds of the second paragraph explicity addresses.
